# How do redirect someone with .HTACCESS?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect someone who types http://domain.com/+abc (this should only apply to alphanumeric characters with a preceding "+" sign) into the address bar to http://domain.com/abc without the preceding "+"?

Would I have to do this via .htaccess? And if so, how? Would it also require some REGEX?

I'd appreciate any help on this! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with .htaccess and it will require regex. Add these lines into yours .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\+(.*) $1
```

This should work.